# Unable to populate a list in reactjs from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a list `app`. I want its item to populate in MenuItem. I tried the following:-

```
{app.map((item, index)=>{
       <MenuItem value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>
})}
```

but I'm getting this error:-

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
```

`console.log(item)` shows `[ "NE", "NO" ]` 
`console.log(app)` shows `[ [ "" , "", "" ], [ "NE", "N)" ] ]`

Comment: what value in `app` ?

Comment: try adding return before <MenuItem value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>

Comment: remove the comma `,` after console.log

Comment: You should return `MenuItem` from `map`

Comment: return `MenuItem` and add key also in the map function to avoid warning.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return something from `map`, In your case you have to return `MenuItem` as

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**`Below will implicitely return the MenuItem`**

```
{
  app.map((item, index) => <MenuItem value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>);
  // without { and }
}
```

or You can explicitly return the **`MenuItem`**

```
{
  app.map((item, index) => {
    console.log(item);
    return <MenuItem value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>;
  });
}
```

**`EXPLANATION`**

Since, you are using `map` here which should be used if we want to map over the array and return something from it and map will return an array of elements and what you want is to map over the `app` array and return `MenuItem` elements because whatever you will return from `map` will eventually become React children.

```
return (
        <div>
            {app.map((item, index) => {
                (
                    <MenuItem value={item} key={item}>
                        {item}
                    </MenuItem>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
```

Above code snippet gets converted to

```
return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, app.map((item, index) => {
    /*#__PURE__*/
    React.createElement(MenuItem, {     // NOTICE, you are not
      value: item,                      // returning any React
      key: item                         // Elements from here
    }, item);
  }));
```

So, you should return from `map`

Comment: Might be useful to add what the difference is between implicit/explicit returns are.

Answer (score 1):

**2 Issue**

1. `console.log(item),` to `console.log(item)`; // comma to semicolon
2. `<MenuItem  value={item}>{item}</MenuItem >` to `return <MenuItem value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>` // need to return